# robocopy to new server and new domain

Tags: domain-controller, file-permissions, robocopy

First question here so I thank you in advance for any input. Simple situation but a little different from the usual ones, so I want to confirm before proceeding.

- Small office with less than 10 users. Partnership ending but both are keeping the D drive data.
- Old server remaining in production is DC and file server.
- New server for new office is not yet a DC. It is now on same network as the old one.
- Need to copy all files and folders on D drive of old server to D drive of new server.
- Do not want to copy permissions.

My plan is to use ROBOCOPY using /COPY:DAT to moves files and folders to new server (again, without permissions). Then I'll move server to new office, make it a DC, create users and give them access to the few folders they need on the D drive, lock down file permissions.

Anything I am missing here or should do differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you create a new domain ? you know that you will have to migrate the 10 users profile on those PC too, and rejoin the PC to the new domain.

Just do a dcpromo as a new DC and copy the file with robocopy with the permission. robocopy with **/MIR** flag multiple time.

When ready change the fileshare location and mapping from each computer (gpo, script, or the way you did it..)